# Could not load type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions from assembly Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1

I have 2 EF Core projects **A** and **B**

Project **A** has .net6.0 target and corresponding packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.7" />
```

Project **B** has .netcoreapp3.1 target and corresponding packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.4" />
```

While referencing **B** to **A** everything builds OK, but on resolving context from **B** inside of the project **A** I am getting the following exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions' from assembly 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Version=6.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
```

Why **B** project's context can't use it's own dependancies from lower version of Postrges package? Is it possible to use it like that, because I can't upgrade the project **B** and I don't want to downgrade project **A**

Answer (score 0):

So the avalaible (exept some exotic non-supported workarounds) options I found are :

1. Multi targeting project B with conditional package reference. For example
   [Multiple target framework project: different versions of the same NuGet package on different frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382251/multiple-target-framework-project-different-versions-of-the-same-nuget-package)
   In my case it's

   `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1'"> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6"/> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.1.22"/> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.22"/> <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.4"/> </ItemGroup>`

   `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'"> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.11"/> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.1"/> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0"/> <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.7"/> </ItemGroup>`
2. Proxy a data request to the context through web api or message queue (depending on type of interactions you do with the context data) as the result breaking the direct reference.